# Find whether file exists or not in HDFS using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have a `shell script` like below. This script prints the path of a file located in `HDFS`

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
path=/user/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
path1=/user/$USER/logs/`date -d "-1 days" '+%Y-%m-%d'`.fail_log

echo filePath=$path
echo filePath1=$path1
```

In the script the `paths` provided are `hdfs` locations

In this script I am getting the filepath.

Now I want to know whether the file actually exists or not in `HDFS`.

If the file exists then only print the filepath or else do nothing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try `-test` option to achieve the same.

> ```
> hdfs dfs -test -[defszrw] HDFS_PATH
> ```
>
> - **`-d`:** if the path is a directory, return 0.
> - **`-e`:** if the path exists, return 0.
>
> Since 2.7.0
>
> - **`-f`:** if the path is a file, return 0.
> - **`-s`:** if the path is not empty, return 0.
> - **`-r`:** if the path exists and read permission is granted, return 0.
>
> since 2.8.0
>
> - **`-w`:** if the path exists and write permission is granted, return 0.
> - **`-z`:** if the file is zero-length, return 0.

Example:

```
if hdfs dfs -test -e $HDFS_PATH; then
    echo "[$HDFS_PATH] exists on HDFS"
    hdfs dfs -ls $HDFS_PATH
fi
```

Reference: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#test

Comment: Did you test the code? Because I was able to get the value only using `echo $?` and comparing it to 0.

Comment: exists is return 0;    `echo "[$HDFS_PATH] not exists on HDFS"` need to `not`

Answer (score 2):

```
path=hdfs://a/b/c

hdfs dfs -test -e ${path}
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "exists !!!"
fi

hdfs dfs -test -z ${path}
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "zero !!!"
fi
```